# SonarQube Admin Password on Docker Container with Postgress DB Engine

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube

**I have lost the Sonarqube Server admin password, want to recover that, any support will be appreciated.**

Environment docker images:

1. sonarqube:7.9.5-community
2. postgres:12.5-alpine

I have gone through the previously answered block but unfortunately nothing worked out.

Best

Comment: Are you able to login to postgres DB??

Comment: Yes I do. *@SouravAtta, Thanks for your reply.*

Answer (score 2):

The Idea is same as mentioned @ [Sonarqube Security Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/instance-administration/security/) under the title "Reinstating Admin Access".

**My Solution:**

I had to spin up fresh Docker container in order to get the default crypted_password value. If you already know/have the crypted password value then no need to spin up fresh containers, just follow the below steps by replacing the crypted_password accordingly.

Below crypted_password value belongs to admin.

1. exec to postgres docker container :

   **docker exec -it POSTGRES-CONTAINER-NAME bash**
2. Inside Postgres Container, login with the Credentials and follow on screen instructions:

   **psql  -U sonar -W**
3. Confirm the Database and Users :

   **select * from users;**

   Output must show a Sonarqube Users Table.
4. Then Update the password to default i.e. admin :

   **update users set crypted_password = '$2a$12$2NA1PhmvfPVwdwq5WeQj.Opb0z4OGYP8s2yPMRRum18bGV5nJK86W', salt=null where login = 'admin';**
5. try login to Sonarqube server with default credentials,

   **ID : admin**

   **Password : admin**

To learn more about @ [Sonarqube Security Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/instance-administration/security/).